# SonarQue's Scanner is wrong about "Serializable" classes

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

SonarQue's Java-Scanner quite often reports "Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable" but is wrong, true?

We have a class tree as follows:

```
public class DTO implements Serializable { /*...*/ }
public class ADTO extends DTO { /*...*/ }
public class AADTO implements Serializable {
  private ADTO adto;
  // ...
}
```

SonarQube now complains about the member variable: "Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable"
but implementing even a marker interface should be a feature that is transitive into child classes. 
We are using these classes for RMI, and the data is transferred to the remote VM, so the message seems proven wrong!

Using SonarQube 5.1.2 with Java plugin 3.4.

Regards from Germany,

blue

Comment: It's wrong. Submit a bug report,

Comment: Bug reports should be submitted to the SonarQube Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: This check should detect such cases. But in order to achieve that, the .class files of DTO and ADTO must be provided to the analyzer through the sonar.java.libraries or sonar.java.binaries properties (this is normally done automatically if you run the analysis with maven). How do you run your analysis and can you share your project configuration ?